# Linear Fit of multidimensional data

Tags: fitting, vector

I am trying to find linear decomposition of vector B (of arbitrary dimension $n$) in the form :

$B = \alpha_{1} C_{1} + \alpha_{2} C_{2} + ...$

where $C_{i}$ are known vectors (of dimension $n$) and $\alpha_{i}$ are scalars (to be determined).

I am trying to do it using `LinearFitModel`, but I have trouble understanding how it works in my case from the Mathematica documentation. I tried :

```
X = Transpose[{C1,C2,C3,X}]
f = Transpose[{C1,C2,C3}]
t = Table[i,{i,1,Length[X]}]
LinearModelFit[X,f,t]
```

but I get the following error :

```
LinearModelFit::fitm: Unable to solve for the fit parameters; the design matrix is nonrectangular, non-numerical, or could not be inverted.
```

Has someone experience with this ?

Many thanks in advance,

Cl38

Comment: `LinearSolve[]` looks to be better for this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to the matrix equation C.x=B, where the columns of C are your vectors Ci.  As "Guess who it is" noted, this can be worked with LinearSolve[], or you can RowReduce[] the augmented matrix [C|B] to find a general solution.